# use socket.io event to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-functional-component

I have a react functional component:

```
function Chat(props) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const inputRef = useRef();

  //The socket is a module that exports the actual socket.io socket
  socket.socket.on("chatMessage", (msg) => {
    setMessages([...messages, msg]);
  });

  const inputChanged = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      socket.sendMessage(inputRef.current.value)
        .then(() => {
          //do something
        })
        .catch(console.log);
      inputRef.current.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
      <div>
        {messages.map((msg, i) => <ChatMessage key={i}>{msg}</ChatMessage>)}
        <input ref={inputRef} onKeyPress={inputChanged} />
     </div>
  );
}
```

But when i update the state from the `socket.socket.on("chatMessage"` , I get an error

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

And the socket tells me it took to long to respond, and some recursiveness starts happening.

How should i go about updating my component state from a socket event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to setup the socket listner within the useEffect function otherwise on every re-render a new instance will be created and old instances will continue to listen and cause memory overflows and unexpected state update errors. Also do clear your socket listners

```
function Chat(props) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
      //The socket is a module that exports the actual socket.io socket
      const addMessage = (msg) => setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, msg]);
      socket.socket.on("chatMessage", addMessage)
      () => {
            // turning of socket listner on unmount
          socket.off('chatMessage', addMessage);
       }
  }, [])

  const inputChanged = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      socket.sendMessage(inputRef.current.value)
        .then(() => {
          //do something
        })
        .catch(console.log);
      inputRef.current.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
      <div>
        {messages.map((msg, i) => <ChatMessage key={i}>{msg}</ChatMessage>)}
        <input ref={inputRef} onKeyPress={inputChanged} />
     </div>
  );
}
```

// P.S. Make sure you are using callback method to update state

Comment: Thanks, it workd, I'm new to hooks.
But why does the component unmount? and why does returning a function that turns off the listener, removes the error?

Comment: The error can sometimes be misleading. However if you do not clear your listnerer even though the component is no longer rendering, the listener will continue to execute and will try to set state for a component that doesn't exist

Comment: Hi can you help me out? in my useEffect i am trying to update the existing state but i keep getting undefined when try to find a specific chat in my state

Answer (score 0):

Socket is side effect.

```
useEffecf(() => {
  const callback =  (msg) => {
    setMessages([...messages, msg]);
  };

  socket.socket.on("chatMessage", callback);

  return () => {
    socket.socket.off("chatMessage", callback);
  };
}, []);
```