# Use current variable value within socket.on subscriber

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

So I have the following issue, I have a `socket.on("someevent", someFunction)`, and my problem is that the code in someFunction should execute only under a certain condition, so:

```
const [modalOpened, setModalOpened] = useState(false);

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const handleSetData = (data) => {
  !modalOpened && setData(data);
}

socket.on("someevent", (data) => {
  handleSetData(data);
});
```

The problem is that, once that event listener is created, it takes whatever the current value of `modalOpened` is, and sticks to it, and I want it to always use the currently actual value, so how do I pass it by reference?

I have tried creating another function, but it still doesnt work with it:

```
const checkModalOpened = () => { return modalOpened }
```

It still sticks to whatever value it caught.

Comment: That should work, I use it the same way. Where and how do you change the state of modalOpened?

Comment: It is being changed in a parent context, if i log modalOpened outaide of the functions it has the accurate value, but its stuck on false inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your event listener into a `useEffect` function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const listener = (data) => {
    if (!modalOpened) {
      setData(data);
    }
  };
  socket.on("someevent", listener);
  // You also want to remove the event listener
  // when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    socket.off("someevent", listener);
    // this will prevent any leak from your component
  };
}, [modalOpened]);
```

This will ensure that the listener is bound when the component mounts and

Comment: Yes, thats how I ended up doing it last night, I could not find a way around having to turn off sockets and turn them back on, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaa, I knew I have solved this before!!!!
You have to setup the listener in useEffect, otherwise it is recreated on every rerender.
Details here: [use socket.io event to update state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042360/use-socket-io-event-to-update-state)